# how to set file name as input value to other input

Tags: javascript

below script is working fine . but issue is its showing file name in alert box . but i want file name as input value .. I tried many times but i didn't get expected outfile . Example If i selected first file i want input value in id="0" like that if it is 2nd one I want value in id="2"

```
<input type="file" class="input"/>
<input type="file" class="input"/>
<input type="file" class="input"/>
<input type="file" class="input"/>
<input type="file" class="input"/>
<input id="0">
<input id="1">
<input id="2">
<input id="3">
<input id="4">
<script>
var inputArray = document.getElementsByClassName('input');

for(var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++){
    inputArray[i].addEventListener('change',prepareUpload,false);
};

function prepareUpload(event)
{
    var files = event.target.files;
    var fileName = files[0].name;
    document.getElementById("0").value = fileName;
    alert(fileName);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Try to use something else for IDs instead of the numbers. Seems to work fine for me though: https://jsfiddle.net/1zbtnfzr/

Comment: input value is displaying in only one input .. but i want values in different inputs if I uploaded first file I want value in first input . if it is 2nd file i want value in 2nd input

Comment: Ah ok .. so it works but you just need a bit more code.

Answer (score -1):

Your IDs are not valid.
See this question:

[What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Here is a little demo of what I think you tried to do:

```
<input type="file" class="input" name="input1" />
<input type="file" class="input" name="input2" />
<input id="input1">
<input id="input2">

var inputArray = document.getElementsByClassName('input');

for(var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++){
  inputArray[i].addEventListener('change',prepareUpload,false);
};

function prepareUpload(event)
{
  var files = event.target.files;
  var fileName = files[0].name;
  document.getElementById(event.target.getAttribute('name')).value = fileName;
  alert(fileName);
}
```

Depending on the use case you might want to use a *data* attribute instead of the name.

Comment: But that doesnt cause the issue.

Comment: I edited the answer. You were not completely clear what your issue is.